# How to use Custom Links in VFP or Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, customsetting

I have created `Custom Links`so that I can use either in Visualforce page or apex controller but I'm trying to figure out how to call this custom links?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @sfdcfox: I do not want to hardcode the url in VFP or controller instead i want to read the url from custom links, also when move from one sandbox to another we do not have to modify the code rather modify the custom links.

Comment: If you want use custom links in your vf page, try adding the below line with your custom link to the vf page. <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Calculation__c.My_custom_link)}">My link</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have global variable [$Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm) to access the custom button and custom links.

So you should be using like

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.Account_Upload)}">
    Upload new Account
</apex:outputLink>
```

Different [valid values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm) for the $Action

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice. I'd forgotten about $Action.